# I use Figma offline despite I am connected with internet

Tags: user-interface, graphics, user-experience

I've logged in Figma. I downloaded the app. My connection with internet is fine. I cannot use fully wersion of the program. I don't know why. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the project you are trying to edit is from someone else, the person might not give you right to edit it, so the design mode is not available for you, you can only do comment on the project. 
Try to create your own project, if the problem remain it another issue.